# Change Root in a symfony 2.8 App on AWS - Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

need some pointers here!

I have successfully deployed my app onto elastic beanstalk on Amazon Web Services, but i'm having an issue with my root, basically its the  /web that its running from, how can i change it so that the app runs straight from the url?

I played around with deploying a symphony app to azure before and used a web.config file. can i do the same here?

the web.config for azure looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="BlockAccessToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/web/*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

any suggestions would be great so thanks in advance for any help!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that your application is currently being served from `http://myproject.elasticbeanstalk.com/web/`, and you want to remove `/web` instead serving directly from `http://myproject.elasticbeanstalk.com/`.

You need to update the `document_root` for your environment. There are a couple of ways to do this:

### AWS Control Panel

The quick 'n' easy solution is to change the `document_root` from the EB console itself.

[image]

Steps:

1. Log into AWS and go to the Elastic Beanstalk control panel
2. Click on the Environment that you want to edit
3. From the menu on the left, click **Configuration**
4. Under **Web Tier** click the gear icon on the **Software Configuration** panel
5. Under **Container Options** there is an input option for **Document Root**
6. Change this value to `/web`
7. Click **Apply** at the bottom of the page

Done! Your environment should start updating.

### Project Configuration/CLI

Alternatively, you can define this step in your project's `.config` file in `.ebextensions` under `option_settings` and update from the command-line.

The following is an example from a Symfony2 project I have deployed to EB, which includes a value for `document_root`:

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /web
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: composer_options
    value: --optimize-autoloader
```

Your environment should be updated with any new settings the next time you run `eb deploy` for your environment.

You might also be able to update this setting via the command-line with `eb setenv`, which is useful for setting envvars for your environment via command-line but I haven't tried that with `document_root`, so YMMV.

Hope this helps :)